# Editable plug in Select tag issue:: JSon data from Java Servlet, is not populate into the select tag using JEditable plug in

Tags: jquery, json, jeditable, html-select

I am using Jeditable for edit, Tablesorter for Table sorting and filtering with JQuery.
I have a table. Click on a selectClass column I would like to update the data using drop down. Drop down is loading the JSON data using loadurl tag, with a servlet call. I am able to print the JSON response from server side, but unable to get the data in select tag.

Servlet code to send the JSON data::

```
  if   (type.equals ("getAllCategoriess")){                
                  System.out.println(" Inside of getAllCategoriess ");
                    List<String> categories = new ArrayList <String> ();

                    categories.add ("Comedy");
                    categories.add ("Thriller");
                    categories.add ("Action");
                    categories.add ("Romantic");
                    categories.add ("Science");
                    categories.add ("News");
                    categories.add ("Political");

                    JSONArray arrayObj1=new JSONArray();
                    for (String str: categories)
                        arrayObj1.add (str);
                    out.println(arrayObj1.toString());

                    System.out.println ("array Object for getAll Categories:: "+arrayObj1.toString());                
                }
```

Script to load the data ::

```
$(".selectClass").editable('http://localhost:9090/Application1/query?type=setCategory', {
        indicator: "<img src=\"images/indicator.gif\">",
        loadurl : 'http://localhost:9090/Application1/query?type=getAllCategoriess',
        type   : "select",
        submit : "OK",
        style  : "inherit"
    });
```

I am not getting the data into select tag/ drop down. If I use data tag instead of loadurl, it is working:. Data tag is below

```
data    : "{'0':'Please select...', '1':'Comedy','2':'Harror','3':'Thriller', '4': 'Atcion', '5': 'Romantic', '6' : 'Science'}"
```

But I want to load the data from JSON array.

Please help me to resolve this?